# BIRT - onCreate script not running

Tags: birt, oncreate

I have a report designed in BIRT 2.3.0 using dynamic columns generation.
The report has open, fetch and beforeOpen script for different sections that initialize the column headers and values, and some onCreate script replacing the column headers and values according to some value suffix.
Running this report with RunAndRenderTask method is working fine.
When running separately, with RunTask and RenderTask, the onCreate scripts don’t run (the replace operation is not performed).
I’ve been debugging the application line by line and I can’t find why these scripts are not running.
Please, any help will be great.
Regards

Comment: Adding some more information, the open script gets information from a system and initialize column headers like 
entrydate_string, product_string
and row headers like
product + ‘@’ + warehouse

The onCreate script replace these strings with the final ones

Comment: Have you tried with BIRT 4.2.1 or 4.3.x? While these versions are old, too, they are several years younger than 2.3.0 and good enough for using in production. Maybe this is a long-fixed bug.

Comment: According what I found, there were some similar bugs about this issue, but they were all fixed in earlier versions. Beside, I can not upgrade the version to a new one; it's installed in several client instances and it has to perform all the test cycle to be approved.